# Pig nested for each clarification

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

i have below clarification on order operator in pig.
could anybody please clarify it.

Sample code

```
x = LOAD '/home/hadoop/Desktop/HadoopSetup/input/Data/StockData' using PigStorage(',') As (exchange:chararray, symbol:chararray, date:chararray, open:double, high:double, low:double, close:double, volume:long, adj_close:double);

y = GROUP x by symbol;

z = foreach y {
            t = order x by open DESC;
            k = limit t 1;
            generate group, k.volume;
                };
```

question

> y relation contains group,x  in it's schema. x is not relation so how
>   can we select x in below order statement since it is not a relation.
>   Could  anybody elaborate on below statement?

```
t = order x by open DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache pig uses concept of ***Field Projection*** when using nested FOREACH statements, in your code it is using ***Nested Projection***

So when you use FOREACH it means for every record that is present in Y (every record present in Y is grouped X) , now apache pig do not need grouped X to be put in separate relation he can refer it from already projected field i.e., Y.

Note a point here that FOREACH operation will perform for every record/line present in Y.

- Project-range can be used in all cases where the star expression ( *
  ) is allowed.
- Project-range can be used in the following statements: FOREACH, JOIN,
  GROUP, COGROUP, and ORDER BY (also when ORDER BY is used within a
  nested FOREACH block).

follow this link: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html